# .NET MVC Core current SDK not supporting .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am following a video on PluralSight and I went to github.com/aspnet/Mvc to download the source files and follow along.

When I downloaded the files and tried to run the program, I ended up with:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard
>   2.0.  Either target .NET Standard 1.6 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard
>   2.0.  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets    126

I have also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732236/the-current-net-sdk-does-not-support-targeting-net-standard-2-0-error-in-visua) post and downloaded the 2.0 Core separately, but it is still giving me this error. Even after I updated to Visual Studio 15.3.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit**

After deleting the source files and re-cloning the project I open the project and I am now getting this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error KRB1001 Package references have not been pinned. Run
>   './build.cmd /t:Pin'.
>           Also, you can run './build.cmd /t:Restore' which will pin *and* restore packages. 'build.cmd' can be found in 'C:\Users\ty_lo\source\Mvc\'.   VersioningWebSite   C:\Users\ty_lo\source\Mvc\Directory.Build.targets   12

Comment: Global.aspx is ASP.NET MVC not ASP.NET Core MVC. Best place to start is the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/

Comment: you downloaded 2.0, but did you change your project settings to 2.0?

Comment: @Alexan I changed the version in the global.json file, but I didn't change it in the project settings. How is this done?

Comment: project properties

Answer (score 0):

**FIX**: I seemed to have fixed my solution by going to Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> General and then making sure the "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" is checked.